# How to merge and add tuple objects?

Tags: python

I have the following two lists:

```
  list_A : [(129, -0.32, 0), (17, -0.22, 0)]  
  list_B : [(33, -0.12, 1)]
```

I want to create a list_C as:

```
  list_C : [(33, 129, -0.44, 0), (33, 17, -0.34, 0)]
```

In other words,

1. The 1st element of list_B is inserted as the first element in each tuple in the list_A.
2. Then, the 2nd element in the list_B is added to the 2nd element in each tuple in the list_A.
3. The 3rd element in each tuple in the list_A is preserved (3rd element of the list_B is ignored).

Can anyone help me on this manipulation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `list_B` is a list of tuple, so its 1th element is `(33,-0.12,1)`, not `33`.

Comment: You should not include 'thank' in posts. See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: Can you advise where you got stuck? Seems the most basic method involves only list / tuple indexing by position (see Omg's answer).

Comment: In fact, my lists are more complicated than my lists in this post. I simplified my descriptions too much. Anyway, it keeps on creating a parenthesis for certain elements using omg's approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like the following:

```
C = [(B[0][0], a[0], a[1] + B[0][1], a[2]) for a in A]
```

Comment: I edited my original question to describe my problem in details.

Comment: @east you couldn't update the question. as it is another question.

Comment: So I need to post as a new question?

Comment: @east yes, you do.

Comment: @east you should refer to this question to short your explanation in the second question.

Comment: How can I refer to this question in my new question?

Comment: @east click on the share button in the bottom of your question to get the share link for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51570012/3768871